# Micro frontend Architecture using AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We are attempting to implement a micro frontend architecture using AWS ECS. So far, we have a cluster with 1 fargate service, 1 fargate task with 2 containers, and a single ALB. Each container hosts a micro frontend using NGINX listening on a unique port (e.g. 3000, 3001, etc.) and has a corresponding target group with a path pattern (e.g. /containerA* and /containerB*). The default target group is the first container.

Each micro frontend will be referenced within the main site using a relative path and displayed using an iframe (e.g. `<iframe src="/containerB" />`).

**Overview:**

We have two micro frontends: A and B. A is the main micro frontend and displays all children in an individual iframe. All routes should go directly through A to display the child micro frontend. For example:

- http://localhost:3000/ --> displays A
- http://localhost:3000/containerA --> displays A
- http://localhost:3000/containerB --> displays B inside of A

**Problem:**

We're able to get this architecture working. However, at http://localhost:3000/ or http://localhost:3000/containerA the iframe for http://localhost:3000/containerB displays a 404 not found error, which indicates a routing problem within the NGINX config. for B. If the client navigates to http://localhost/containerB the same problem occurs. However, the content of B is not displayed in an iframe inside of the content for A. The content of B is displayed as its own page.

**containerA**

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.bak:

```
server {
    listen 3000;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
}
```

**containerB**

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.bak:

```
server {
    listen 3001;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. In your opinion, is this the best infrastructure to use for a micro frontend architecture (e.g. 1 cluster, 1 fargate service, 1 fargate task with 2 micro frontend containers each with their own target group)?
2. How can we achieve correct routing between containers? Meaning, http://localhost/containerB displays the content of B inside of A rather than B as a page of its own.
3. What is the correct NGINX config. to use for container B so that the index.html is displayed?

**Misc.**

- Container A and B uses ReactJS.
- Ideally, each micro frontend should be completely decoupled from container A.
- Each micro frontend should be able to use it's own preferred library (e.g. ReactJS, Vue, AngularJS, plain HTML and JS, etc.).

Comment: From where do you call the localhost command? It obviously can't be a curl/wget or browser request from your local laptop

Comment: @BernieLenz, will you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean. The containers each have their own target group behind an Application Load Balancer.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you're running a web page in a browser on your laptop. That page has iFrames that point to localhost. Is my understanding right?

Comment: The page has iframes that point to a relative path (e.g. /containerB). Localhost isn't specified anywhere. The localhost links in the question are just for examples.

Comment: Thanks, I see, that was a bit confusing to me. In order for "http://alb_url:3000/containerB " to get port 3000 serve content from 3001 I suppose you need to setup a proxy forward in nginx running on 3000. I believe this is done using proxy_pass...